# Is it possible to respond with a HttpResponseMessage prior to executing the code in a Web API 2 ODataController with [EnableQuery]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

So I have the following code:

```
public class MyODataController : ODataController
{
        [EnableQuery]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
                //Code
        }
}
```

[EnableQuery] will not allow just any form of ResponseMessage() response though. What I would like to do is the following:

1. Intercept the message prior to reaching the Get() method in MyODataController.
2. Have the code here decide whether to continue calling the Get() method in MyODataController or to immediately return a HttpResponseMessage that isn't restricted by [EnableQuery] and that does not need querying.

Is this possible and if it is, how?

Edit: Please note that the decision in step 2 above is NOT based on the incoming request message, so I don't necessarily need that in that step.

Comment: This is relatively trivial to do with Filters. Action Filters in particular are often used to, well, filter actions, and conditionally return a different response. Or, if it's authorization-related, you can write authorization filters too. Finally, you can also insert a custom middleware before the `ApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseEndpoints()` in your pipeline. I think it's relatively difficult to give a good, specific answer, because there are so many options, and it's unclear what sort of architectural or structural requirements or preferences do you have. :)

Comment: Thanks @leaky. I managed to solve my problem. I created a custom ActionFilterAttribute with an OnActionExecuting method and added it to my Get method. At first it made no difference. However although the order of attributes normally shouldn't make a difference it did in this case.
Didn't work:
[EnableQuery]
[MyCustomAttribute]

Works:
[MyCustomAttribute]
[EnableQuery]

Comment: Yes @Marty78, because the `EnableQueryAttribute` is actually implemented as an `ActionFilterAttribute`, which completely takes over the processing of the action: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/EnableQueryAttribute.cs. Honestly, I personally don't like how they suggest OData integration, and I tend to just implement OData-like filtering and ordering, because those are the parts that are actually useful to me usually. Like this: https://github.com/baratgabor/MyWarehouse/blob/master/src/Infrastructure/Common/Extensions/QueryableExtensions.cs

Comment: This type of logic really clashes with concept of OData and REST in general, you are suggesting that under certain conditions that are **NOT** dependant on the incomming request, that a different structured response will be returned. Sounds like you should do this with either a custom function endpoint to provide the alternate response or do this with MVC/WebAPI routes, not OData routes.